# Auto incrementing a column based on another

Tags: mysql, innodb

[image]

I have an application which generates invoice_id's. These id's need to be unique. The issue is that a client can have more than one invoice depending on what plan they are on. It could be 2, 3 or 4. So I made a column with extra invoice_id's which I called invoice_idA and invoice_idB.

Now I do not know how to handle the incrementing of the invoice_id. It would be easier if it is one invoice so I can just use an auto_increment but I will have an issue because if there is more than one invoice_id in a column for one client, there could be duplicates.

Looking at the picture,

1. I need a way to make invoice_id increment to 1008 based on the value in invoice_idA of 1007.
2. If I insert a value in invoice_idB like 1008, how will I increment invoice_id to read from it because it could be 2,3 or 4 extra invoice numbers. I believe even if there was a way I may need to know the exact column to increment from but in this case, it could be invoice_idA or invoice_idB.

Comment: Check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412341/how-should-i-store-guid-in-mysql-tables) about GUID columns in MySQL. Perhaps they would suit your needs? Be sure to check out Jeff Atwood's [post](http://blog.codinghorror.com/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids/) (one of the founders of StackExchange).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

romeo, before I craft a reply, I want to ask: Is there any chance you have the opportunity to edit the schema in this case?

If you can, you definitely should, because the problems you're running into are because of denormalization.

## Normalization of the schema

From your example table above, it appears this should be split into at least two separate tables. From the information you've given you should have an `invoice` table and a `client` table, with (pseudocode) definitions as

```
CREATE TABLE invoice (invoice_id, client_id, invoice_date);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE customer (client_id,service_id, phone_number);
```

Using these tables, you can establish a foreign key relationship from `invoice (client_id)` to `customer (client_id)`, allowing a many-to-one relationship between `invoice` and `client`.

Subsequently, you can obtain all invoices pertaining to a particular client via

```
SELECT * FROM invoice JOIN client ON invoice.client_id = clinet.client_id
WHERE client = ...
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you have special requirements for the values of your id, do *not* use `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  There are too many cases (crashes, `DELETEs`, `REPLACEs`, `INSERT IGNORE`, etc) where the numbers will behave in unexpected ways.